# Edit scss stylesheets via cpanel's file manager?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have website that I was working on before my laptop broke. Now I'am stuck with old Windows XP computer which doesn't really does the job. Before my laptop broke, I uploaded my web site online as subdomain. I tried editing my scss file online via cpanel -> file manager, but no changes were made.

Is it possible to make modifications via this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better make changes to your `.scss` file and compile it online here -

http://www.sassmeister.com/

And update both your `.scss` & `.css` through file cpanel, so that for the time being your changes can be reflected on your site, and in future when your laptop fixes you can have a updated `sass` file also.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was doing it wrong: I tried editing the scss file that was uploaded on cpanel, which was wrong. Then I tried editing the main.css file, and now I can see the changes:-)

Comment: You're not doing it wrong; you have the right idea of changing the `.sass` file, however your server won't know what to do with it without installing sass. See my answer above, and whatever changes you make to your `.css` file I highly recommend making a backup of if you aren't using version control.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a compiler that will convert the sass into CSS. The server will not do it alone through cPanel without the installation of a compiler. Also, a file watcher will need to be set up to watch the `.sass` file for changes to automatically re-generate a `.css` file which the browser (and therefore the site itself) can understand. [Here are instructions on installing Sass](http://sass-lang.com/install).

Once you install Sass, you'll need to set up the watcher, you can do this within sass if you'd like, [instructions here](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-1).

The tricky part is this involves command-line stuff, which most default installs of cPanel don't let you do easily.

If you don't have shell access to your server, you may be out of luck until you [upgrade your machine](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help).

---

**Beware!!! editing just the CSS file, if you ever go back to your site on a working computer than can compile `.sass`, it will by default overwrite your CSS changes you made, and without version control; will be very difficult to get back.**